# How to Export Data in CSV in Multiple Sheets in a Single File?

Tags: php, cakephp, export-to-csv

I have developed `CAKEPHP` code for exporting data in `CSV format.`

It is working fine , but my question is if i want to export data at multiple sheet or in other words if i want to export data at **"Sheet 1" and "Sheet 2" and "Sheet 3" in a single CSV file**, how can i make it possible?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

sorry to inform you but this is not possible in CSV file.You can do it with excel

Comment: You disappointed me. May be any solution available. This should be a comment not an answer.